# How to filter/change column values in a data frame?

Tags: r

I have a huge dataset, and one of the columns, let's call it Col10, has integers from 1-10. I want to update and change this column so if the number is even, the value becomes "even", and "odd" otherwise. I can obviously iterate through a for-loop, but I was thinking that there would probably be a more elegant way to do this in R.

I've tried using `ifelse` statements present within the brackets, but I seem to be getting errors when trying this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> Col10 = c(1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,4,2,5,10)
> Col10 <- ifelse(Col10%%2==0, "Even", "Odd")
> Col10
 [1] "Odd"  "Odd"  "Even" "Odd"  "Even" "Odd"  "Even" "Odd"  "Odd"  "Even" "Even" "Odd"  "Even"
```